# Spyder Anaconda - select Python interpreter

Tags: python, 17.10, configuration, anaconda, spyder

I have installed Anaconda (x64 Linux) and I am running its Python 3.

When I type `which python`, I get

```
/home/hinckelbc/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Now to display the version, I type `python -V`, and I get

```
Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

Which is normal, since I am running Python 3 from Anaconda

If I launch Spyder from the terminal by simply typing `spyder`, it will launch and I see that the Python interpreter is indeed the Python 3 from Anaconda, as shown below:

```
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 18:10:19)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 6.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

!which python
/home/hinckelbc/anaconda3/bin/python

! python -V
Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

The Spyder running on my machine is the following:

```
hinckelbc@BCArg:~$ which spyder
/home/hinckelbc/anaconda3/bin/spyder
```

In order to avoid opening the terminal all the time and typing `spyder`, I have created the following `spyder.desktop` file `~/.local/share/applications/spyder.desktop`, which looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Spyder
Exec=/home/hinckelbc/anaconda3/bin/spyder
Icon=/home/hinckelbc/anaconda3/pkgs/spyder-3.2.6-py36_0/info/icon.png
Terminal=false
```

I then could find Spyder with the Super key, which was then added to by launcher, by dragging and dropping (Gnome 3, Ubuntu 17.10)

However, when I open Spyder by clicking on the icon, now on my favorites, I get:

```
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 18:10:19)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 6.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

! which python
/usr/bin/python

! python -V
Python 2.7.14
```

Which does not agree with the [python interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592879/how-to-change-python-version-in-anaconda-spyder) I set manually on Spyder, as shown below:

[image: Spyder preferences screenshot]

Does anyone know how to solve this, i.e. to get Python 3 running on Spyder with the desktop icon I have created and added to my favourites?

Answer (score 0):

Your environment is different.

The spyder terminal inherits the PATH variable from its parent, the Spyder process, who has different env:
- When launching spyder from PATH is the one of shell, which includes .../conda/bin because of your .bashrc / .zshrc
- When launching from .desktop, the env is the one with /etc/profile (and maybe .profile ?)

In short, one solution is to launch through your shell:

```
Exec='bash -c .../spyder'
```

...and make sure that you add conda/bin to your PATH in .bash_profile, or see `[How to load .bashrc from “bash -c”][1]`.

Comment: When I add this to my `spyder.desktop` file in ubuntu the spyder icon disappears

Comment: I found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101620/how-to-load-bashrc-from-bash-c) worked.  Adding `Exec=bash -i -c "/home/coyote/anaconda3/bin/spyder %F"`